# Jquery if visible show another div, else hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have an whole page overlay, when mega menu is active. I am trying something like this:

```
function overlay_toggle() {

        if ($('.mega-sub-menu').css("visibility") == "hidden") {

            $('#twc-page-overlay').css({ "visibility": "hidden" });
        }

        else {
            $('#twc-page-overlay').css({ "visibility": "visible" });
        }

    }
```

Currently its doing doing the job. Any ideas what I am missing here?

Thank you!

HTML something like this:

```
<header>
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <ul class="mega-sub-menu"></ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</header>

<div id="twc-page-overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That won't work, just use `.is(":visible")` to check visibility, and `.show()` to make it visible and `.hide()` to hide it

```js
if ($('.mega-sub-menu').is(":visible") === false) {
  $('#twc-page-overlay').hide();
} else {
  $('#twc-page-overlay').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul class="mega-sub-menu">
          <li>Heheh</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id="twc-page-overlay">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ammar. Still not working. Also, I would like to show #twc-page-overlay when .mega-sub-menu is visible. I switch the .hide and .show. Still not working thought

Comment: Sorry i just wrote the opposite code, use `$('.mega-sub-menu').is(":visible") === false` instead of `$('.mega-sub-menu').is(":visible")`, because we are checking if it's not visible.
Updated my answer, check now

Comment: Still not working. No errors on the console. Maybe we can try to switch.. like  hidden, hide #twc-page-overlay and else show #twc-page-overlay ??

Comment: can you provide some related html?

Comment: Can i share my website link with you?

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in one line:

```
$('#twc-page-overlay').toggle($('.mega-sub-menu').is(':visible'));
```

If you want to use `visibility` rather than `display`, you can do the same thing with toggleClass:

```
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }

$('#twc-page-overlay').toggleClass('hidden', $('.mega-sub-menu').is(':hidden'));
```

Both .toggleClass() and .toggle() accept a boolean value to apply/remove or show/hide respectively.